# execute a javascript 'method' by default when calling other methods from an object

Tags: javascript, dry

I have read that it is a good practice to not use too many global variables in javascript, so I am trying to package some functions related to navigation buttons of my app in a single variable like this:

```
var navs = {
  projects:   function(){
    main.removeClass().addClass('showing_projects');
    //... other code
  },
  line_items: function(){
    main.removeClass().addClass('showing_line_items');
    //... other code
  },
  media:      function(){
    main.removeClass().addClass('showing_media');
    //... other code
  }
}
```

So that I can do

```
navs.projects()
```

to show the projects. My question is, I have this function showNotify() that I need to run after calling any of the navs.projects(), navs.line_items(), or navs.media(). I feel that it is not DRY to have this showNotify() line added to each of these three properties/methods. Is there a way that I can have showNotify() run each time these I call these three methods?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could parameterize the parts of each of those functions that are different:

```
var navs = {
    addClassAndNotify: function(className, fn) {
        main.removeClass().addClass(className);
        fn();
        showNotify();

    }
}
```

And used like this:

```
navs.addClassAndNotify('showing_media', function() {
    // showing media code
});
```

You might also create a function generator, like this:

```
function create(className, fn) {
    return function() {
        main.removeClass().addClass(className);
        fn();
        showNotify();
    }
}
```

And then create your functions like this:

```
var navs = {
    projects: create(function(){
        //... other code
    }),
    line_items: create(function(){
        //... other code
    }),
    media: create(function(){
        //... other code
    }),
}
```

But I don't think calling `showNotify` in each function is a big deal.

Comment: I do like the idea of parameterizing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a violation of DRY to add `showNotify()` to the end of each of these methods. A violation of DRY would be copy/pasting the contents of `showNotify()` instead of calling it.

As far as I know, there is no way more succinct than adding the calls to achieve your goal. Even if there were, it would be a very bad idea to do so because calling the functions would have some effects not visible at all to the person reading the code for them.

Comment: thanks for the input, at least I can feel a bit better that if I do have to repeat calling a certain function inside functions that are themselves similar to each other isn't always not DRY.